# hex string to SHA256 digest in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto

I have a string that contain a SHA256 digest in hexadecimal like blow:

```
"257612236efae809c23330ab67cf61f73aec938503f3ce126c34c6a32059f5f0"
```

and I want to convert it to `hash.digest()` that can be  like  below:

```
b'%v\x12#n\xfa\xe8\t\xc230\xabg\xcfa\xf7:\xec\x93\x85\x03\xf3\xce\x12l4\xc6\xa3 Y\xf5\xf0'
```

how can I achive this?
 I use `Crypto.Hash` and `python 3.3.2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify("257612236efae809c23330ab67cf61f73aec938503f3ce126c34c6a32059f5f0")
b'%v\x12#n\xfa\xe8\t\xc230\xabg\xcfa\xf7:\xec\x93\x85\x03\xf3\xce\x12l4\xc6\xa3 Y\xf5\xf0'
```